# scope not updating after loading csv file with d3

Tags: javascript, angularjs, csv, d3.js, angularjs-scope

I have a node server that sends a csv file to the client when I hit the `/scheduleE` route. In my controller I hit this route and update the scope. I'd like the scope on the page to update.

```
app.controller('ETableCtrl', function($scope){

    $scope.payments = []
    $scope.$watch('payments', function(){
        console.log('value changed!')
    })

    d3.csv('/scheduleE', processData('01/01/14'), function(payments){
        $scope.payments = payments;
        console.log($scope.payments);
    })
})
```

In the view `$scope.payments` stays and empty array and "value changed!" only logs once, at the beginning. `$scope.watch("payments")` does not update in the view. It remains an empty array.

However, the code logs out the array of objects to the console. Why won't my scope update in the view?

Answer (score 1):

The callback is happening outside of the scope of the Angular app. Try calling `$scope.$apply();` after you update $scope.payments.

There are better ways to do this, but you can at least confirm the issue.

Comment: works! I had tried `$scope.$broadcast()` and $scope.$emit() but $apply() is the correct one

Comment: More generally, any time that something runs in a d3 callback (attribute calculation functions, .on() callbacks, etc) and touches the Angular scope, you will want to wrap it in $scope.$apply(function (s) { Do stuff with scope 's' here }).